# Logical diagramming software

Tags: windows, web-apps, osx, diagram

I am looking for software for a client, that will allow them to graph large and complex logical trees.

It would need to be able to have it so you can specify some boolean and numerical variables, and then in the diagram, in order to get from one node to the next the conditions would have to be specified and met, or rather it would travel the path of the conditions that are met.

Another great feature would be that you can specify values for all the variables, and watch the diagram run.

Finally if the diagram could optimize itself logically that would be even better.

Comment: Are you looking for Petri Net tools?

Comment: a) A solution must be available for Windows *and* OS X? Or is one of them sufficient? b) Does it have to be a web app, or can it a be a web app and/or a local client, or is it required to be both?

Answer (score 3):

Provided input can be accepted in a text file, then [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) seems to fit your needs as written, and there is a Windows MSI for the current stable version, and you can either download .pkg files or `brew install graphviz` on Mac OSX.

Key points:

- Layout of graphs is logically optimised.
- No GUI, the interface is command-line processing of data files. This may or may not be a problem, you don't say in the question.
- You cannot "watch the diagram run", but you have specified this is a nice-to-have.

Answer (score 3):

For this type of issues I recommend [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). It uses [graphml](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) as storage format, runs on most platforms, does a nice job optimizing layout and works for extremely large graphs.

Youtube video [yEd Graph Editor in 90 seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmSTwKw7dX4) .